# Which mountain bikes are purposefully built to be 27.5 and 29 compatible, similar to Rocky Mountain Pipeline

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, 29er

I'm looking to get a bike that was designed to handle both 27.5 and 29 wheels so that i can have a single bike and swap wheels when feel like modifying the riding characteristics.

I was looking at the Rocky mountain Pipeline that was designed to handle both wheel sizes and has a 9 position flip switch to help adjust the geometry based on the wheel size being used.

Was wondering if anyone knows of other companies and models that are designed with this same option in mind.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of any bikes that are marketed as such.  Have you considered doing it "hack/bodge" style and use 29-er with 27.5" wheels (or 27.5-er with a 29" front wheel)?

Comment: @Superman.Lopez yes iim considering doing this but while looking for a bike i found the Rocky Mountain Pipeline which is actually marketed as 27.5+/29 and so was wondering if any other bikes were marketed as such.   I like the Ride 9 flip chip in that bike as well which lets you play with the geometry a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

27.5x2.8 and 29x2.4 have approximately the same outside diameter of the inflated tire. Same with 27.5x3 and 29x2.5-6ish. All 27+ bikes can run 29; it's implicit whether they're marketed as such or not, although many are. In the other direction, bikes presented as native 29, there may not be enough side clearance for a 27+. Older 29ers would typically not have that kind of clearance to spare, but the whole 27+/29 interchangeability thing got big around 2016 and many made since then have it.

Comment: Yes this I understand but was wondering what other bikes and models have features like the flip chips to maintain the geometry while switching wheels.  Or any other mechanism to modify and maintain geometry between the 2 wheel sizes.  But like you say if you use tires which result in same outer wheel width then the geo doesnt change when switching wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Genius, Ransom and Gambler are designed to be used with either 29" or 27.5" wheels.

> ONE FRAME TWO WHEEL SIZES
>
> With our mountain bikes, we try to achieve ultimate versatility. These
> specific models can switch from 27.5" to 29" or from 24" to 26" wheels
> with nothing more than the flip of a chip. No need to change the fork,
> all you need to do is flip a shock mount chip, change your wheels and
> off you go. The flip chip allows us to maintain a similar BB height
> when switching from one wheel size to the other which is key to
> keeping handling similar for both wheel sizes.